# request.on(readable) called twice for single request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I am new in nodejs and now days i am learnig http module.

> I wrote a js program for node to check if content-type is application/json in request, then it should console at 'readable' event.
>
> What happening is: on a single request 'readable' event called twice and print the value first time and second time it returns null.

Here is Code:

```
var connect = require('connect');


function jsonParse(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json' && req.method == 'POST') {
        var readData = '';
        req.on('readable', function() {
            console.log('inside readable ' + req.read());
            readData += req.read();
        });

        req.on('end', function() {
            try {
                req.body = JSON.parse(readData);
            } catch (e) {
            }   
            next();
        })
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

connect()
.use(jsonParse)
.use(function(req, res) {
    if (req.body) {
        res.end('JSON parsed !' + req.body);
    } else {
        res.end('no json detected !');  
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

> I am calling this like:
>   [image]
>
> output is : 
>   inside readable {
>   "foo":"asdf"
>   }
>   inside readable null

Please guide me how can i handle this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share the console

Comment: this is the result printed via console statements:                                          inside readable { "foo":"asdf" }                                                                          inside readable null

Comment: can you guide me why this called twice? few suggest that browser send one more request for favicon icon. Then how can we handle this.

Comment: you can use it as a middleware

Comment: are you using express or what?

Comment: not much aware about the setup. But explicitly i am not using any express type of thing. I just setup connect middleware framework and then start the coding. Basically i am reading it from 'beginners node js by basarat ali syed'

Comment: @SawaiSingh did you find the reason for the issue? I'm at the same point as you were. also reading the book. And I can't figure out why it's called twice respectively why a null is added to the end. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should only read from the request when data is available, so when `req.read()` does not return `null`. You can check this with a `while` loop.

Replace:

```
var readData = '';
req.on('readable', function() {
    console.log('inside readable ' + req.read());
    readData += req.read();
});
```

With:

```
var readData = '';
req.on('readable', function(){
    var chunk;
    while (null !== (chunk = req.read())){
        readData += chunk;
    }
});
```

Comment: Very good answer. Care to explain why it works? I'm wondering why there is no function to call 'end' - it seems like it auto-detects that there is nothing more to read.